# Cron job with CodeIgniter using wget

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron, wget

I am pretty new to setting up cron jobs.  What I've done so far is set one up to run every 5 minutes using the following script:

```
*/5 * * * * wget -q localhost:8888/example/index.php/controller/function
```

When I run just the wget part from the command line, it works perfectly.  But in the crontab, while the logs show it being ran every 5 minutes, nothing is happening.  Am I missing something easy?  Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: is wget in the $path of whatever shell cron is using? check that account's mail for the cron logs as well.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance on this, but how would I determine which shell the cron is using?

Comment: you can try adding `--output-file=logfile` to see whats going on

Comment: you can force a particular shell with `SHELL=bash` or whatever in the crontab. then make sure wget is available in that shell's path. otherwise just give an absolute /usr/bin/wget path instead.

Comment: @MarcB that worked.  If you put it as an answer, I'll accept it.  Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can force a particular shell with

```
SHELL=bash
*/5 * etc...
```

or whatever in the crontab. Then make sure wget is available in that shell's path.

Otherwise just give an absolute /usr/bin/wget path instead.

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/wget etc...
```